# Dividing integer with numpy.array returns array with zeros

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I seem to have some problems dividing a integer with an numpy.array.. 
Doing this seem to return a array of zeroes, instead of decimals values..

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> length = 257
>>> length = 256
>>> x = np.array(range(0,length)
... )
>>> x
array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,
        13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,
        26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,
        39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,
        52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,
        65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,
        78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,
        91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103,
       104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116,
       117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129,
       130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142,
       143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155,
       156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168,
       169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181,
       182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194,
       195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207,
       208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220,
       221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233,
       234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246,
       247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255])
>>> x*1/length
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0])
>>>
```

Why is it returning zeros?

Comment: can't reproduce this, I get all floats

Comment: Because you are dealing with all ints and is reproducible on `Python2.x` . For floating pt result, use : `from __future__ import division`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it is doing an integer division.  Try this

```
x*1/256.0
```

Comment: Ended up just type cast it to float.. an bam.. proper division :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the array consists out of integers, and in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) `/` is defined as *integer division* which round down the result, so `99/100` is considered to be `0`.

You can first cast to a `float`:

```
x.astype(float)*1/length
```

A float is a floating point and such datastructures - putting it bold - support a numbers with decimal dot.